# GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm still learning and I've been following tutorials on firebase auth with reactjs. Now I'm branching off into functionalities the tutorial doesn't cover (anonymous sign-in & linking to google) and I think I'm not understanding correctly how to use firebase's linkWithPopup.

I'm getting TypeError: *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.default.auth.GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor when I try do it. Here is the code:

firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})
export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
```

AuthContext.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import firebase, { auth } from '../firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const anonLogin = () => {
        return auth.signInAnonymously();
     }

    const linkWithGoogle = () => {
        var googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        auth.currentUser.linkWithPopup(googleProvider)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('linked correctly');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    }

useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user)
            setLoading(false)
        })
        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup,
        login,
        logout,
        resetPassword,
        updateEmail,
        updatePassword,
        getUuid,
        updateName,
        anonLogin,
        linkWithGoogle
    }
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
}
```

Will appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: [Here is a semple tuturial you can follow up](https://blog.logrocket.com/user-authentication-firebase-react-apps/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Firebase reference is potentially a reference to your Firebase App rather than the Firebase library which contains the constructors for the providers.
try importing the Firebase library directly, or creating the providers inside your firebase.js file for you to export.

*firebase.js*

```js
export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

*AuthContext.js*

```js
import firebase, { auth, googleProvider } from '../firebase'
```

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick. I tried that before and had some errors but tried again after your answer and it worked. So glad I finally got this figured out, thanks again!